# Написання з великої літери займенника "Ви" (також у відповідних відмінках)

Tags: orthography, велика-мала-літера, займенники, пошанна-множина

Чи відповідає нормам правопису написання займенника Ви з великої літери?

Професор Ющук І.П. у своєму Практикумі з правопису і граматики української мови (ЮЩУК І. П. Практикум з правопису і граматики української мови.— К.:
Освіта, 2012.— 270 с.)  допускає вживання великої букви у займеннику "Ви". 
Зокрема, ч. 6 § 6. Вживання великої букви: "6. З великої букви пишуться слова, вжиті в шанобливому чи піднесено-переносному значенні: звертаюся до **Вас**, дорогий учителю; наша **Батьківщина**; **Збройні Сили**; **Високі Договірні Сторони**."

В той же час Український правопис, схвалений НАН (як редакція 2015 року, так і 2012 року) не зазначає такого випадку вживання великої літери.

Answer (score 11):

Чинний **[Український правопис 2019 року](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf)** унормовує написання *Ви* з великої букви в певних випадках:

> **§ 60. Велика буква в особливому стилістичному вживанні**
>
> 2. З великої букви пишемо займенники Ви, Ваш як форму ввічливості у
>    звертанні до однієї конкретної особи в листах, офіційних документах тощо:
>    *Повідомляємо Вам…, Вітаємо Вас…, у відповідь на Ваш запит…*

До речі, проф. Пономарів, [член Української національної комісії з питань правопису](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/416-2015-%D0%BF), ще у 2010 [казав](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2010/03/post-15.html):

> ...радіослухач уважає, що написання Ви з великої літери є порушенням правопису. Я ставлюся до такого написання позитивно, бо така практика спирається на традиції української, і не тільки, епістолярної спадщини. Ось уривок з листа Лесі Українки до українського композитора й літературознавця Філарета Колесси: *„Високоповажаний добродію! Дуже-дуже дякую Вам за відповідь, та ще з такою доброю звісткою"*. Думаю, що правопис має нарешті взаконити таке написання.

Таке написання тепер справді внормоване, але цю норму [трактують](https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/30025623.html) як таку, що має обмежене призначення:

> **7. Слова «ви», «ваш» тощо завжди пишемо з малої літери, якщо тільки це не лист із персональним зверненням до однієї особи з виявом особливої ввічливості.**
>
> Унормоване написання слів «Ви», «Ваш» тощо з великої літери: це робиться тільки як форма ввічливості у звертанні до однієї конкретної особи в листах, офіційних документах тощо, адресованих безпосередньо цій людині – але в текстах іншого характеру літера завжди мала.

Тобто новий припис щодо написання *Ви* з великої букви не означає, що написання цього займенника з малої (на позначення однієї особи) завжди буде помилкою. Як [підкреслює](https://www.the-village.com.ua/village/business/business-ethics/287497-lyudina-z-velikoyi-bukvi-chi-varto-vikoristovuvati-formu-zvertannya-vi) мовознавець Олександр Авраменко:

> З великої літери «Ви» пишеться лише за шанобливого звертання до однієї особи. І не будь-де, а тільки у ділових документах або вітальних листівках, запрошеннях чи ділових листах.

Коли, до прикладу, звертаєшся до колеги чи клієнта в месенджері, писати *ви* з великої не обов'язково - а то й зовсім не варто.

Answer (score 7):

З великої літери пишемо:

> 4) пошанні звертальні й прощальні форми в офіційному та приватному
>   листуванні: Пане, Добродію, Друже та ін.; Пане Президенте, Пане
>   Голово, Ваша Королевська Величність, Ваша Святість та ін.; Ваш, Твій
>   та ін." (Жайворонок В.В. Велика чи мала літера: Словник-довідник. -
>   К.: Наук. думка, 2004. - С. 184-185).

Хоча звертання до поважних людей у множині має глибоке коріння (у словнику староукраїнської мови з XV ст.), вживання великої літери в таких займенниках у приватному та діловому листуванні повністю перенесено з російської мови. Це не правило, а узвичаєне вживання, яке іноді подається в довідниках з ділової мови. Наприклад, Паламар Л., Кравець Г. Мова ділових паперів, К., 1993, С. 93:

> До речі, займенник Ви в листах, офіційних документах тощо пишеться з великої літери. Цим підкреслюється повага до адресата.

Варто звернути увагу на те, що при займеннику *Ви* складенний іменний присудок може стояти як у формі множини, так і у формі однини.

Наприклад:

> *Ви задоволені? Ви задоволена? Ви задоволений?*

Якщо ж при займеннику *Ви* стоять слова *який*, *якийсь*, *такий*, *один*, *весь*, то присудок ставиться в однині:

> *Яка Ви красива! Який Ви галантний!*

Помилковим є використання *ви* з великої літери, якщо говорять про двох або більшу кількість осіб.

Comment: Дякую! В тому то й річ, що багато науковців такий випадок вживання великої літери виокремлюють, а от Український правопис (Інститут мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні, НАН України, Інститут української мови НАН України. Український правопис, НВП «Видавництво "Наукова думка" НАН України», 2015) - чомусь ні.

Answer (score 6):

> В той же час Український правопис, схвалений НАН (як редакція 2015 року, так і 2012 року) не зазначає такого випадку вживання великої літери.

Не зазначає і, як на мене, досить слушно. Якщо такого правила немає у чинному правописі, отже його недотримання не може бути помилкою, отже це вже справа не мовознавства, а етикету, чи то пак традиції. Часто так звана "пошанна множина" використовується не лише в офіційному існуванні (ніби самої по собі форми множини недостатньо), а й у рекламі (Шановний Клієнте, Ви - унікальна людина, а унікальні люди купують лише в нас. І пам'ятайте, наша корпорація дбає про Вас, купіть і переконаєтеся!)

Постає цікаве запитання: як множина може бути непошанною, якщо вже ми звертаємося до когось конкретного?

У німецькій мові займенник *Sie*, згідно з мовною нормою, може писатися з великої літери навіть у формі множини (звертаючись до кількох осіб), ніби щоб підкреслити, що когось ми поважаємо, а Когось Дуже поважаємо. Є в цьому щось від манупуляції, щось невловиме, але трохи підступне.

Comment: Маленька поправка: в німецькій мові займенник Sie в значенні "ви" **завжди** пишеться з великой літери, незалежно від кількості осіб, до яких звертаються. Але річ у тім, що в німецькій займенники "ви", "вона" і "вони" збігаються за написанням і з маленької пишеться sie лише в значенні "вона" і "вони".

Answer (score 0):

У німецькій мові є і варіант написання до групи осіб на "ти" з маленької літери - це "ihr". тобто правило таке: якщо Ви звертаєтеся до групи осіб, у якій Ви би зверталися до кожного окремо на "Ви", то до всіх пишете і кажете вічливу форму "Sie". Якщо Ви звертаєтеся до групи осіб, у якій Ви із кожним окремо на "ти", то пишете і кажете "ihr".
Але саме смішне, що у німецькій мові (не пам'ятаю, чи збереглася ця норма після нещодавньої реформи) навіть звертання на "ти" і, відповідно до групи осіб, з якими ти на "ти" у листах з великої літери, якщо хочуть показати повагу :). Тобто "Ich habe gehört, dass Du morgen bei uns bist". "Ich habe gehört, dass Ihr morgen bei uns seid". Принаймні, так пишуть мені всі німці і швейцарці :)

Comment: Цей допис сильно виграв би, якби містив пояснення, чому приклад німецької мови, що належить до германської групи, має впливати на українську. Чому, наприклад, не англійська — також германської групи, — де *you* пишеться з малої літери, але є форма *you all* та *you guys* для звернення до групи людей?